# Count of nested arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have this MongoDB schema Buzzer

```
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56cd9c103ff0020300fa1135"
    },
    "title": "50x kliky",
    "timing": "2x týdně",
    "user": "Stejk",
    "history": [
        {
            "title": "50x kliky",
            "datum": "11.09.2016",
            "done": false
        },
        {
            "title": "50x kliky",
            "datum": "11.09.2016",
            "done": true
        },
        {
            "title": "50x kliky",
            "datum": "11.09.2016",
            "done": true
        },
        {
            "title": "50x kliky",
            "datum": "11.09.2016",
            "done": true
        },
        {
            "title": "50x kliky",
            "datum": "11.09.2016",
            "done": true
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

and i want get count of arrays where done is true. how to do it, i am total lost. I dont now how to make it happends. Help please.

Thanks lot for help

Comment: which count do you mean?

Comment: Hello, i want count items where done is true. I use Mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to do it through [`aggregation`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) as below.

```
 Buzzer.aggregate([
    // unwind the history array
    {$unwind: '$history'},
    // filter the done field is true document
    {$match: {'history.done': true}},
    // count the result
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', count: {$sum: 1}}}
 ], function(err, doc) {

 });
```

Comment: Thanks lot :) Thats it! :)

Answer (score 0):

And just one another question. How to make this. (look at comments)

```
    BuzzerListekSchema.statics.getBuzzerListekDetailPercentage = function(req, response, res){
  // Function1
  this.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$history'},
    {$match: {'history.done': true}}, //Filtr
    {$group: {_id: req.params.id, count: {$sum: 1}}}
 ], function(err, c){
   if(err){
     res.status(500).json({succes: false, msg: 'Error'});
   }
   else {
    // Here is result c
    // {_id: ubuiabiufbuiab, count: 5}
   }
 });

 // Function2
 this.aggregate([
   {$unwind: '$history'},
   {$group: {_id: req.params.id, count: {$sum: 1}}}
], function(err, c){
  if(err){
    res.status(500).json({succes: false, msg: 'Error'});
  }
  else {
    // Here is result c
    // {_id: ubuiabiufbuiab, count: 5}
  }
});
  //Here i want reach a percent of percent=Function1/(Function2/100) and send it by JSON
  //res.json({succes: false, msg: percent});

};
```